# Prove $\cos^{-1}(x) = 2\sin^{-1} \sqrt{ \frac{1-x} {2} }$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I'm attempting to prove this using inverse function theorems but unsure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually best to start from the more complicated side and see how things can simplify. Here it ends up with the double-angle formulae for $\cos y$.
$$\begin{align}&y=2\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}2}\\
\implies&\sin\frac y2=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}2}\\
\implies& 1-2\sin^2\frac y2=x\\
\implies&\cos y=x\\
\implies& y=\cos ^{-1}x\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Put $x=\cos(2t)$, then $\displaystyle\frac{1-x}{2}=\frac{1-\cos(2t)}{2}=\sin^{2}(t)$